# ExtJS 3 dateDisabled from store

Tags: arrays, store, extjs3, datefield

Can someone please help me. I'm trying to assign dynamically the value of disabledDates attribute of my datefield

```
xtype: 'datefield',
disabledDates: disabledDates
```

This is the code to get the store and build the dynamic "disabledDates" array

```
var storeFechasOcupadas = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
     url: 'modules/citas/agendar/server/crudAgendar.php?operation=fechasOcupadas',
     root: 'data',
     id: 'id',
     fields: ['dias_laborables']
 });

 var disabledDates = [];
 storeFechasOcupadas.load({
      callback: function(record, operation, success) {
            for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
                 disabledDates.push(record[i].data['dias_laborables']);
             }
       }
  });
```

The store response is like this

```
{"success":true,"data":[
    {"id":12,"dias_laborables":"2013-08-10","disponible":false},
    {"id":16,"dias_laborables":"2013-08-15","disponible":false}
]}
```

what I want to get is something like this

```
disabledDates = ["2013-08-10","2013-08-14","2013-08-15"]
```

but what I see with console.log(disabledDates)

```
[]
0   "2013-08-10"
1   "2013-08-15"
2   "2013-08-07"
3   "2013-08-19"
remove  function()
__proto__   []
```

and even if I try to get disabledDates[0] it returns undefined

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that your date field is already constructed before the data from the Ajax request is returned. Try creating your form inside the store load event **after** the array is actually filled.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your time. The disabledDates array is available before the creation of the form. The problem I have is that I can get this structure ["2013-08-10","2013-08-14","2013-08-15"], instead I'm getting the object []
0   "2013-08-10"
1   "2013-08-15"